# How to turn BTWifi and BTWifi-with-FON off on a BT homehub router / modem

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, bt-infinity

I've got a BT Homehub 3 router / modem combination, as well as distributing my private wpa2 wifi network. It's also out putting both BTWifi and BTWifi-with-FON public wifi; how can I turn these off?

I've gone to http://bthomehub.home whilst connected to the router but couldn't find the settings. Is it done in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do it through their website. Have a check over this [help guide](http://bt.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/12958/~/how-do-i-opt-out-of-bt-fon%3F)